# Is this a DEFAULT memory leak when activity reopens? (Android)

Tags: android, memory, memory-leaks, android-activity

I am testing a simple android app which only has one single Hello world Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        long total = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
        long free = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
        Log.d("TEST MEM LEAK ", "max:" + Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024 + "K, total:" + total / 1024 + "K, free:" + free / 1024 + "K");

    }
}
```

This is the 1st time App opened, and I dump the men info by:

**`$adb shell dumpsys meminfo com.example.Testmemleak`**

```
** MEMINFO in pid 1506 [com.example.Testmemleak] **
                    native   dalvik    other    total
            size:     3212     2819      N/A     6031
       allocated:     3200     2377      N/A     5577
            free:       11      442      N/A      453
           (Pss):      726      856      992     2574
  (shared dirty):     1404     4156     1420     6980
    (priv dirty):      664      436      628     1728

 Objects
           Views:        0        ViewRoots:        0
     AppContexts:        0       Activities:        0
          Assets:        2    AssetManagers:        2
   Local Binders:        5    Proxy Binders:       11
Death Recipients:        0
 OpenSSL Sockets:        0

 SQL
            heap:        0       memoryUsed:        0
pageCacheOverflo:        0  largestMemAlloc:        0
```

this is the 2nd time dump info:

```
** MEMINFO in pid 1506 [com.example.Testmemleak] **
                    native   dalvik    other    total
            size:     3320     2819      N/A     6139
       allocated:     3268     2438      N/A     5706
            free:       51      381      N/A      432
           (Pss):      824      994     1082     2900
  (shared dirty):     1396     4136     1364     6896
    (priv dirty):      760      532      708     2000

 Objects
           Views:        0        ViewRoots:        0
     AppContexts:        0       Activities:        0
          Assets:        2    AssetManagers:        2
   Local Binders:        7    Proxy Binders:       13
Death Recipients:        1
 OpenSSL Sockets:        0

 SQL
            heap:        0       memoryUsed:        0
pageCacheOverflo:        0  largestMemAlloc:        0
```

And this is log after I exit and re-enter app by pressing BACK and app icon several times:

```
01-01 13:38:36.669    1506-1506/com.example.Testmemleak D/TEST MEM LEAK﹕ max:32768K, total:2819K, free:469K
01-01 13:39:51.206    1506-1506/com.example.Testmemleak D/TEST MEM LEAK﹕ max:32768K, total:2819K, free:395K
01-01 13:41:16.005    1506-1506/com.example.Testmemleak D/TEST MEM LEAK﹕ max:32768K, total:2819K, free:344K
01-01 13:41:25.486    1506-1506/com.example.Testmemleak D/TEST MEM LEAK﹕ max:32768K, total:2819K, free:326K
01-01 13:51:22.286    1506-1506/com.example.Testmemleak D/TEST MEM LEAK﹕ max:32768K, total:2887K, free:508K
01-01 13:51:25.380    1506-1506/com.example.Testmemleak D/TEST MEM LEAK﹕ max:32768K, total:2887K, free:489K
01-01 13:51:30.819    1506-1506/com.example.Testmemleak D/TEST MEM LEAK﹕ max:32768K, total:2887K, free:470K
01-01 13:51:33.268    1506-1506/com.example.Testmemleak D/TEST MEM LEAK﹕ max:32768K, total:2887K, free:452K
01-01 13:51:36.382    1506-1506/com.example.Testmemleak D/TEST MEM LEAK﹕ max:32768K, total:2887K, free:433K
01-01 13:51:39.007    1506-1506/com.example.Testmemleak D/TEST MEM LEAK﹕ max:32768K, total:2887K, free:415K
01-01 13:51:41.397    1506-1506/com.example.Testmemleak D/TEST MEM LEAK﹕ max:32768K, total:2887K, free:396K
01-01 13:51:43.794    1506-1506/com.example.Testmemleak D/TEST MEM LEAK﹕ max:32768K, total:2887K, free:377K
01-01 13:51:46.143    1506-1506/com.example.Testmemleak D/TEST MEM LEAK﹕ max:32768K, total:2887K, free:359K
01-01 13:51:48.833    1506-1506/com.example.Testmemleak D/TEST MEM LEAK﹕ max:32768K, total:2887K, free:340K
01-01 13:51:50.970    1506-1506/com.example.Testmemleak D/TEST MEM LEAK﹕ max:32768K, total:2887K, free:322K
01-01 13:51:53.143    1506-1506/com.example.Testmemleak D/TEST MEM LEAK﹕ max:32768K, total:2951K, free:367K
01-01 13:51:57.246    1506-1506/com.example.Testmemleak D/TEST MEM LEAK﹕ max:32768K, total:2951K, free:348K
01-01 13:51:59.215    1506-1506/com.example.Testmemleak D/TEST MEM LEAK﹕ max:32768K, total:2951K, free:330K
01-01 13:52:01.396    1506-1506/com.example.Testmemleak D/TEST MEM LEAK﹕ max:32768K, total:3015K, free:375K
01-01 13:52:03.273    1506-1506/com.example.Testmemleak D/TEST MEM LEAK﹕ max:32768K, total:3015K, free:356K
```

It seems that the heap size and proxy/local binders keep increasing after exit and enter the app, Why? Is is a default "memory leak"?